# nginx docker container as reverse proxy for services running in docker containers

Tags: django, docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, owncloud

I have nginx running in a docker container which I want to use as reverse proxy for services running in docker containers. ATM I have two services, django and owncloud.

Both services works when accessing them directory e.g. `localhost:4000` and `localhost:5000`.

When I'm accessing `localhost/owncloud` I get `502 Bad Gateway`
Nginx log:
`2020-04-27T13:21:54.852082794Z 2020/04/27 13:21:54 [error] 6#6: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET /owncloud/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://172.18.0.4:4000/", host: "localhost"`

When I'm accessing `localhost/django` I get `page not found` from Django, which is fine, but I if I try to access `localhost/django/admin` I get `page not found` from Nginx.
Nginx log:
`2020-04-27T13:29:11.173933857Z 2020/04/27 13:29:11 [error] 6#6: *4 "/etc/nginx/html/sv/admin/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.18.0.1, server: , request: "GET /sv/admin/ HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"`

I'm new to Nginx and have messed around with the `nginx.conf` a lot with no success. Here are the relevant files:

`/docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
networks:
  nginx-net:
```

`/nginx/docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  internal-nginx:
    build:
      context: ./nginx
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: web-nginx
    container_name: nginx
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    networks:
      - nginx-net
    depends_on: 
      - internal-django
      - internal-owncloud
```

`/nginx/Dockerfile`

```
FROM nginx

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx-raw.conf

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf || true
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY html /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
```

`/nginx/nginx.conf`

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;

    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log off;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    client_max_body_size 30000M;

    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

    server {
        listen  80 default;

        location /django/ {
            proxy_pass http://internal-django:5000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            rewrite ^/django(.*)$ $1 break;
        }
        location /owncloud/ {
            proxy_pass http://internal-owncloud:4000;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            rewrite ^/owncloud(/.*)$ $1 break;
        }
    }
}
```

`/owncloud/docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'

volumes:
  files:
    driver: local
  mysql:
    driver: local
  backup:
    driver: local
  redis:
    driver: local

services:
  internal-owncloud:
    image: owncloud/server:${OWNCLOUD_VERSION}
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - ${HTTP_PORT}:8080
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
    environment:
      - OWNCLOUD_DOMAIN=${OWNCLOUD_DOMAIN}
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_TYPE=mysql
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_NAME=owncloud
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_USERNAME=owncloud
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_PASSWORD=owncloud
      - OWNCLOUD_DB_HOST=db
      - OWNCLOUD_ADMIN_USERNAME=${ADMIN_USERNAME}
      - OWNCLOUD_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${ADMIN_PASSWORD}
      - OWNCLOUD_MYSQL_UTF8MB4=true
      - OWNCLOUD_REDIS_ENABLED=true
      - OWNCLOUD_REDIS_HOST=redis
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "/usr/bin/healthcheck"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - files:/mnt/data      
    networks: 
      - nginx-net

  db:
    image: webhippie/mariadb:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=owncloud
      - MARIADB_USERNAME=owncloud
      - MARIADB_PASSWORD=owncloud
      - MARIADB_DATABASE=owncloud
      - MARIADB_MAX_ALLOWED_PACKET=128M
      - MARIADB_INNODB_LOG_FILE_SIZE=64M
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "/usr/bin/healthcheck"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql
      - backup:/var/lib/backup
    networks: 
      - nginx-net

  redis:
    image: webhippie/redis:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - REDIS_DATABASES=1
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "/usr/bin/healthcheck"]
      interval: 30s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 5
    volumes:
      - redis:/var/lib/redis
    networks: 
      - nginx-net
```

`.env`

```
OWNCLOUD_VERSION=10.4
OWNCLOUD_DOMAIN=localhost
ADMIN_USERNAME=admin
ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
HTTP_PORT=4000
```

`/owncloud/Dockerfile`

```
FROM owncloud/server
EXPOSE 8080
```

`/django/docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3'
services:
  internal-django:
    build:
      context: ./django
    ports:
    - "5000:5000"
    restart: unless-stopped
    container_name: django
    image: web-django
    networks: 
      - nginx-net
```

`/django/Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.7
COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app
CMD ["python3", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:5000"]
EXPOSE 5000
```

**EDIT 1**
Running `docker network inspect web_nginx-net`

```
[
    {
        "Name": "web_nginx-net",
        "Id": "ae511269418b963e1d347d3776903161cfbaf68dd024700e35204ffce98b5503",
        "Created": "2020-04-23T00:00:46.073855454+02:00",
        "Scope": "local",
        "Driver": "bridge",
        "EnableIPv6": false,
        "IPAM": {
            "Driver": "default",
            "Options": null,
            "Config": [
                {
                    "Subnet": "172.21.0.0/16",
                    "Gateway": "172.21.0.1"
                }
            ]
        },
        "Internal": false,
        "Attachable": true,
        "Ingress": false,
        "ConfigFrom": {
            "Network": ""
        },
        "ConfigOnly": false,
        "Containers": {
            "4c74c231d03483793bf113544e712befe8a6eba7a52eb430d4231dc2f50d598f": {
                "Name": "web_db_1",
                "EndpointID": "e72ad329b7814df8dbd8eb0ade7e6335508d17546bdb9d23065e3a380c0e3b23",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:15:00:04",
                "IPv4Address": "172.21.0.4/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c0b1d933dae330fb9cd06ce5636338750c1dcb6c1d77d62535aaec0933f24c0e": {
                "Name": "nginx",
                "EndpointID": "0fd231bdc4349f39129bc29bfa065356fad302b4564ce5ebd12c3e6c9342259e",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:15:00:06",
                "IPv4Address": "172.21.0.6/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c3835352577257841cec782fa6aed5a3dbcba5da9b02167338f7dfc0836e2cea": {
                "Name": "web_internal-owncloud_1",
                "EndpointID": "fcf5241f793a3de30bcfff51ebcc9075f66322d7e13320baf7754d464a3f676d",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:15:00:05",
                "IPv4Address": "172.21.0.5/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "c974cec76348654f93f77e76ab109287dde3049a9508204f0ad9f3c7906b6d2d": {
                "Name": "django",
                "EndpointID": "86500ce8e5db41b4a6f527d39b0c578ff5fccd9cbfd4382815d73271e1b05ecb",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:15:00:02",
                "IPv4Address": "172.21.0.2/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            },
            "eeeaed65ec89283d52ebfafb5d3770e731a8490c44217041d3d407c41a8707d4": {
                "Name": "web_redis_1",
                "EndpointID": "275754d8bd4d7a12d86280cd6812ad7a461079913aee185ba6d67b16815e1205",
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:15:00:03",
                "IPv4Address": "172.21.0.3/16",
                "IPv6Address": ""
            }
        },
        "Options": {},
        "Labels": {
            "com.docker.compose.network": "nginx-net",
            "com.docker.compose.project": "web",
            "com.docker.compose.version": "1.23.2"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Try to run docker inspect nginx-net and check if all 3 containers are visible there ?

Comment: @AdityaT I updated the question with the output from inspect.

Answer (score 0):

You will need multiple changes, try using below steps:-

In your internal-cloud docker-compose file, add line `container_name: owncloud` 
For example :

```
internal-owncloud:
image: owncloud/server:${OWNCLOUD_VERSION}
restart: unless-stopped
container_name: owncloud #add this line
ports:
  - ${HTTP_PORT}:8080
depends_on:
  - db
  - redis
environment:
  - OWNCLOUD_DOMAIN=${OWNCLOUD_DOMAIN}
  - OWNCLOUD_DB_TYPE=mysql
  - OWNCLOUD_DB_NAME=owncloud
  - OWNCLOUD_DB_USERNAME=owncloud
  - OWNCLOUD_DB_PASSWORD=owncloud
  - OWNCLOUD_DB_HOST=db
  - OWNCLOUD_ADMIN_USERNAME=${ADMIN_USERNAME}
  - OWNCLOUD_ADMIN_PASSWORD=${ADMIN_PASSWORD}
  - OWNCLOUD_MYSQL_UTF8MB4=true
  - OWNCLOUD_REDIS_ENABLED=true
  - OWNCLOUD_REDIS_HOST=redis
healthcheck:
  test: ["CMD", "/usr/bin/healthcheck"]
  interval: 30s
  timeout: 10s
  retries: 5
volumes:
  - files:/mnt/data      
networks: 
  - nginx-net
```

In your nginx file, remove rewrite lines :

```
    location /django/ {
        proxy_pass http://django:5000;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        #rewrite ^/django(.*)$ $1 break; //remove this
    }
    location /owncloud/ {
        proxy_pass http://owncloud:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        #rewrite ^/owncloud(/.*)$ $1 break; //remove this
    }
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Still connection refused for `owncloud`. For Django it works a bit.. if I type the exact url e.g. `http://localhost/django/sv/admin/login/?next=/sv/admin/` I get the login page but without any css, js stuff. One of the errors in the log: `2020-04-27T19:59:30.669185731Z 2020/04/27 19:59:30 [error] 7#7: *20 open() "/etc/nginx/html/static/admin/css/login.css" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.21.0.1, server: , request: "GET /static/admin/css/login.css HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost", referrer: "http://localhost/django/sv/admin/login/"` but this is if I use the rewrite for Django.

Comment: You should add "django" as a context url in your django application configuration rather than looking for rewrite.

Comment: For /owncloud application, try ssh to nginx container using command docker exec -it nginx /bin/bash and then use curl command to check connectivity of owncloud app for example curl http://owncloud or http://owncloud:4000 or http://owncloud:8080

Comment: Connection refused when I curl owncloud:4000 from inside nginx container.
I haven't tried adding django as a context yet..

Comment: try with other urls too.

Comment: owncloud:8080 works. So I have changed proxy_pass for owncloud to port 8080. Each service works fine if I set location in nginx.conf to just / . But as soon as I set location to /django or /owncloud it cannot find the page.

Comment: You shouldn't use rewrite directive, and notice I already gave owncloud:8080 in earlier my answer. Go with adding context url to applications so that they will always redirect to that url internally as well otherwise you will see issues with your assets and redirection.